# Show that scalar multiplication gives rise to a map and check for linearity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Show that scalar multiplication gives rise to a map $\mathbb{R} \to Hom(V,V)$ and check for linearity which sends such scalar to "multiplication by that scalar"

Ok, so i kind of have the feeling that this is done showing that if i have a function that can get  a scalar and an element from V to scalar times element from V then this can span V itself.Although this is my only lead, any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. They are referring to the scalar maps $V\longrightarrow V$ defined by "scaling" vectors: $v\mapsto \lambda v$. That map is linear: $\lambda(v_1+v_2)=\lambda v_1+\lambda v_2$ is true since we are working in a vector space.

Write the scalar map from above as $\phi_\lambda:V\rightarrow V$. That is $\phi_\lambda(v)=\lambda v$. We then have a function $$\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \text{Hom}(V,V)$$ defined $$\lambda\mapsto\phi_\lambda.$$